# When does JavaScript interval stops?

Tags: javascript, timer

It may be a naive question but I need to know the answer.

This is my code,

`setInterval(function() { /do stth./}, 1000);`

I never cancel the timer, I need to run it as long as user is on the page, I need to know will it case any memory leak, or when will it stop (ie, browser refresh, browser close)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem can occur when you "do something".  If you have other long running functions or even additional intervals inside the interval (a la Javascript Inception) then you could run into performace issues.

However, in almost all cases, you won't have any problems.

When the user refreshes the browser, the interval will begin anew.  When the browser is closed then all activity stops.

As long as the user doesn't refresh the browser or leave the page then the interval will never end.

Comment: thanx, so the browser does it automatically, any link to read in detail what are  the things browser does when it refreshes the pages, or shut down.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  The browser only does what you tell it to.  Can you be more specific of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

it stops when you leave the page.  It shouldn't cause leaks.